# hybris Backoffice application throwing NullpointerException

Tags: nullpointerexception, impersonation, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm working with hybris 5.2. When I access my backoffice application and log in, I get the NullpointerException below.

This is before even creating an extension to extend the backoffice extension that comes with the hybris commerce suite.

Looks like some context is missing a site, but I'm not sure which context and how to set a site to it.

Also, I'm logging in as Admin, so I don't know why the `ImpersonationService`. I thought the Admin was supposed to just have access to everything.

This is the error message from the console:

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/08/17 18:39:52.984 | [0;31mERROR [hybrisHTTP6] [DefaultImpersonationService] Couldn't determine the site from the context. Hence the site related session state won't be adjusted.
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/08/17 18:39:52.985 | [m[0;31mERROR [hybrisHTTP1] [DefaultImpersonationService] Couldn't determine the site from the context. Hence the site related session state won't be adjusted.
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/08/17 18:39:53.487 | [m
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/08/17 18:39:54.298 | Aug 17, 2014 6:39:54 PM org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl handleError:1352
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/08/17 18:39:54.298 | SEVERE: >>java.lang.NullPointerException
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/08/17 18:39:54.299 | >>  at de.hybris.commercesearchbackoffice.widgets.siteselector.data.SiteInternalData.<init>(SiteInternalData.java:33)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/08/17 18:39:54.299 | >>  at de.hybris.commercesearchbackoffice.widgets.siteselector.controller.SiteSelectorController.setDefaults(SiteSelectorController.java:105)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/08/17 18:39:54.299 | >>  at de.hybris.commercesearchbackoffice.widgets.siteselector.controller.SiteSelectorController$1.onEvent(SiteSelectorController.java:93)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/08/17 18:39:54.299 | >>  at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.onEvent(AbstractComponent.java:2742)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/08/17 18:39:54.299 | >>  at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.service(AbstractComponent.java:2713)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/08/17 18:39:54.299 | >>  at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.service(AbstractComponent.java:2654)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/08/17 18:39:54.299 | >>  at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessor.process(EventProcessor.java:136)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/08/17 18:39:54.299 | >>  at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.processEvent(UiEngineImpl.java:1710)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/08/17 18:39:54.299 | >>  at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.process(UiEngineImpl.java:1495)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/08/17 18:39:54.299 | >>  at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execNewPage0(UiEngineImpl.java:464)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/08/17 18:39:54.299 | >>  at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execNewPage(UiEngineImpl.java:316)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/08/17 18:39:54.299 | >>  at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet.process(DHtmlLayoutServlet.java:214)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/08/17 18:39:54.299 | >>  at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet.doGet(DHtmlLayoutServlet.java:135)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/08/17 18:39:54.299 | >>  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/08/17 18:39:54.299 | >>  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/08/17 18:39:54.299 | >>  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/08/17 18:39:54.299 | >>  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/08/17 18:39:54.299 | >>  at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/08/17 18:39:54.299 | >>  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/08/17 18:39:54.299 | >>  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/08/17 18:39:54.299 | >>  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/08/17 18:39:54.299 | >>  at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/08/17 18:39:54.299 | >>  at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/08/17 18:39:54.300 | >>  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/08/17 18:39:54.300 | >>  at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/08/17 18:39:54.300 | >>  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/08/17 18:39:54.300 | >>  at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/08/17 18:39:54.300 | >>  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/08/17 18:39:54.300 | >>  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/08/17 18:39:54.300 | >>  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
```

Comment: Seems that you have session issue, try to clear you cache and check.
Try to update your system as backoffice-item.xml is having BackofficeRole model.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with that. I cleared the cache and the error persists even after I initialize my entire system. It's like I'm missing some kinda essential data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's being caused by the `commercesearchbackoffice` extension.

If you can do without it for now, you can comment it out of your `localextensions.xml` file. You'll have to make do without the nice perspective and widgets that it adds to the backoffice, but since those are not working anyway...

You might also want to have a look at the Search and Navigation module, on the hybris wiki, to see if you didn't miss out on any required configuration.

Comment: It does help, yes. i wish they'd be more specific about 'the site' though.